# Как заменить тег h3 на span в виджете?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как в виджете заменить тег h3 на тег span? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. имеется ввиду стандартный виджет, настраиваемый в админке. На сайте в результате "Меню" будет в теге h3. Подскажите, как убрать тег h3 и заменить его на span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле: `wp-content/themes/{имя_шаблона}/functions.php`
ищите блок кода в котором настраиваются сайдбары.
Например, для шаблона **twentysixteen** это кусок:

```
function twentysixteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 1', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Bottom 2', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears at the bottom of the content on posts and pages.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentysixteen_widgets_init' );
```

Значения `before_title` и `after_title`.

Comment: Во первых не "для шаблона" а "для ТЕМЫ". Во вторых данные манипуляции нужно производить в дочерней теме. В третьих не в каждой теме это вообще будет в фанкшине.